# MySQL Cluster mysqld not connecting to management

Tags: mysql-cluster

Using Ubuntu 22.04 on AWS EC2 for all nodes. ports 1186 and 3306 are open. I'm trying to follow this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-multi-node-mysql-cluster-on-ubuntu-18-04 and everything looks good until it's time to test my connection between mysqld and everything else.

From mysql, SHOW ENGINE NDB STATUS \G shows me results that are almost right:
Type: ndbcluster
Name: connection
Status: cluster_node_id=0, connected_host=172.31.18.230, connected_port=1186, number_of_data_nodes=0, number_of_ready_data_nodes=0, connect_count=0

It's not seeing data nodes or anything though, and it's clear it's not connected with everything else. Similarly, ndb_mgm shows me that it's waiting for a connection from mysqld.